# Conda installs a package that already exists

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

Although I already have numpy installed in my anaconda environment as per `conda list`

```
numpy                     1.15.4                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy-base                1.16.2           py36hc3f5095_0
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py36_0
```

However, when I did `conda install theano`, it tries to install another numpy package with the same version as shown below

```
  added / updated specs:
- theano

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  mkl_fft            pkgs/main/win-64::mkl_fft-1.0.10-py36h14836fe_0
  numpy              pkgs/main/win-64::numpy-1.16.2-py36h19fb1c0_0
  pygpu              pkgs/main/win-64::pygpu-0.7.6-py36h452e1ab_0
  scipy              pkgs/main/win-64::scipy-1.2.1-py36h29ff71c_0
  theano             pkgs/main/win-64::theano-1.0.3-py36_0
```

My questions are:

1. why do I have different versions of numpy (numpy 1.15.4 and numpy-base 1.16.2)?
2. why does anaconda want to install a second numpy package of the same version in its environment?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What SO are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why do I have different versions of numpy (numpy 1.15.4 and numpy-base 1.16.2)?

If you open Conda terminal and `from numpy import __version__` you will probably see that the version is equal to `1.16.2`. But if you open python externally to the Conda, and do the same thing you will probably see the version `1.15.4`. Conda by default maintains the base environment and, as each environment can have its own version of each module, the difference is because of that.

> why does anaconda want to install a second numpy package of the same
>   version in its environment?

This can be explained if you have another active environment (different from the base environment), and the first answer also answers this.

Comment: Hi Hemerson, thank you for your explanation. However, when I ran the command suggested by you in Anaconda Prompt, I got the following error: ```(base) D:\Users\jng09>from numpy import __version__
'from' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```

Comment: You need to run this "comand" in a python terminal or build a little script with those lines of code additionally with `print(__version__)`

Comment: Got it. Thank you! Given your Python knowledge, would you mind having a look at this issue, in particular module numpy core multiarray has no attribute get_ndarray_c_version [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024382/error-theano-gof-opt-optimization-failure-due-to-constant-folding)?

Comment: You are welcome! If my post answered your question, please accept it as the answer (just click in the check button ;)) I will take a look in your other question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the check button. I tried but unable to vote for your answer due lack of reputation. Given your expertise in Neural Networks, I do hope my other question is worth your while. I can send you the file and training data so that you can reproduce the error.